# Keyboard typing in all CAPS and selecting everything

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I bought a MacBook with an M1 chip and am encountering severe problems with the keyboard:

- I can only type in caps.
- If I click on a number only the symbol gets typed and if click on a fullstop the alternate character gets typed such as this: >
- If I select something and I scroll everything gets selected and also when I move a cursor from one position to another.
- If I click on something on the browser everything opens in a new tab and I can guarantee it has nothing to do with chrome settings.
- If I restart my laptop this problem stops momentarily then starts again.

I have tried the following:

- Installed Karabiner
- Started in safe mode
- Pressed Option Command P + P on Startup
- Disabled caps lock

Nothing has worked!

Comment: Since Caps Lock didn't change anything, this sounds like a stuck Shift key. Press both Shift keys and see whether they move the same way as the other keys.

Comment: Otherwise, take it back to wherever you bought it and have it fixed under warranty.

Comment: Try an external keyboard (doesn't have to be from Apple) and see if that works ok.  If so, the internal one is likely damaged.

Comment: Assuming you have the same issue in **safe mode** then boot to **macOS Recovery** and see if you still have the issue. You can use **Terminal** and or **Safari** to test typing in. Have a look at: [Use macOS Recovery on a Mac with Apple silicon](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/macos-recovery-a-mac-apple-silicon-mchl82829c17/mac)

Comment: Thanks, @DarkDust that was the case, so what I did was I disabled both the shift keys through karabiner, and I made my fn key into a shift key. But thanks.

Comment: @MohammedHansa: You're welcome, but if you recently bought it, you should bring it back to your retailer to either have it repaired (for free) or replaced. Not sure about consumer laws where you are, but if the purchase was made recently it's likely you have right to a get a non-faulty device.